# How to Extract Months and also show the totals for that month

Tags: mysql

```
SR_ AREA                   INS_PRODUCT          DATEADD             TOTAL    
Clinical Question             PS               2016-01-06            280
```

I'm trying to show the month by name say January and I want all the totals for the month of January not just for one day in the month.

I got it to show just Month and total how do I get it to show all the months this is the code I have so far.

```
SELECT  DATENAME(MM,GETDATE()) AS MONTH, COUNT(*) AS TOTAL
FROM    S_SRV_REQ WITH (NOLOCK)          
WHERE   (dbo.fn_dstoffset(CREATED) >= '11-15-2015') 
        AND (dbo.fn_dstoffset(CREATED) <= DATEADD(D, 1, '3-31-2016'))
        AND (INS_PRODUCT IN ('PS')) 
        AND [SR_AREA] IS NOT NULL 
        AND (SR_AREA IN ('Clinical Question'))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select date_format(dateadd, '%M'), sum(total)
from your_table
group by date_format(dateadd, '%M')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use MONTH

```
select month(dateadd), sum(total)
from your_table 
group by month(dateadd)
```